# Word processing software that allows drawing and writing at the same time

Tags: osx, drawing, ebooks

I am looking for a word processing software that can write and draw within the same software. Basically, it should have two interfaces to it:

#### Writing

- Distraction-free, as in has a central interface with no unnecessary buttons
- Can support styles.

#### Drawing

- I should be able to quickly switch to drawing mode with a shortcut, etc.
- Support graphics tablets (100% necessary)
- Need not be professional, but at least compares to the free version of [AutoDesk SketchBook](https://www.sketchbook.com/).

#### Additional requirements

- Needs to be for Mac OSX Yosemite
- Needs to be an offline application

#### Optional

- Uses Markdown
- Can export to .epub, .mobi, .pdf, and other major ebook formats (w/ the drawings)

I seriously doubt if any software meets these all of these, but at the very least it should have drawing capabilities within the main interface. Also, preferably this should be under $50. **Absolute max** is $150, though I am a beginning writer, and I don't really wish to spend that much, but due to the extreme constraints, I'm willing if it has *very, very* good bang for buck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you understand the difference between desktop publishing software, and word processing software? If so, which would you like?
If not, look into it and then update the question with clarification..

Hint: If you are making a professional (for publication) book in word processing software, it will require further processing for layout, done in desktop publishing software (which is not a problem, it is how most things are done -- publishers have guys for that)

Comment: I am looking for a word processing software in that sense, however since I'm going to use my own sketches in 70% of the book, to me it doesn't really make sense to keep copy-pasting from another software. So I am looking for a word processing software that allows me to draw within the same interface. Then layout changes can be made after negotiation with my publisher.

Comment: Ok,, goodo, becuase there are very few functional desktop publishing tools for <$150 (The line between word processor and desktop publisher is ever bluring to be fair). And futher export to ebook formats doesn't really matter too much since it will be just for drafts (The ebook export in a desktop publishers are much better)

Comment: Microsoft Word [supports a stylus](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Use-a-pen-to-draw-write-or-highlight-text-on-a-Windows-tablet-6d76c674-7f4b-414d-b67f-b3ffef6ccf53).

Comment: While the Windows version of Word supports a stylus, the Mac version doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word (version 16.42) should meet your needs.

- Distraction-free achieved through *Focus mode*.
- The *print layout* is your drawing mode.
- Supports stylus (at least it supports my Wacom Intuos pretty well) via *Insert Scribble Shape*.
- Works for current macOS version (Sierra as of this writing).
- Works without an Internet connection (after you've downloaded and registered).
- Exports to PDF.
- Not too expensive (about $10/month as part of Office 365).

Failing that, Apple's Pages (version 6.0.5) is a lower-cost option.

- The *Page Layout* mode is your drawing mode.
- Stylus support is rather weak (no freehand mode) but workable.
- Exports to ePub and PDF.
- Comes free with fairly recent macs or about $15 (CMIIW).